# Is it possible to remove the y axis ticks in geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-histogram

As in the title, I am plotting a serials of facet plots of histograms. But I do not want the y axis ticks (counts/density) to show up since it looks cluttered. I used the option `theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())` to remove the y axis ticks but it does not work for `geom_histogram`.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
dd <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))

ggplot(dd, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Is it just not possible to do this with histogram plots, or is there some other way? Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: You've removed the ticks, but if you want to remove the text as well them set `theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `axis.text.y=element_blank()` as well:

```r
ggplot(dd, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: ggplot with ticks and text removed]